# calling back (a notification) from a thread that runs in a service

Tags: android

After starting my app it starts the main activity that starts a service. This service has its basic starting notifications, icon ect. and starts a thread that runs some business logic periodically. How can i make this thread be able to call the service back (which started it) to do some notification about the results? How can i reference the service? I just cant figure it out. Pls help me! thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service will run on the main thread of the application. Have a handler in it and pass the reference of that handler to your thread. The thread can post back messages to the handler. For details about passing data between threads see [this](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html).